# What data structure should I use so that my "calendar" api has maximum performance?

Tags: performance, go, data-structures

I have a micro service, which serves employees work calendars. The original data has the following  file structure:

```
calendars / [year] / [employee].json
```

Contents of [employee].json:

```
{
  // [date]: [hours]
  "2023-02-01": 7,
  "2023-02-02": 7,
}
```

Using Go, I convert all data to these two variables with types `CalendarFast` and `CalendarSlow`:

```golang
type Username = string
type Date = string
type Year = string
type Hours = float64

type CalendarFast map[Username]map[Year][]struct {
    Time  time.Time // "2022-01-01"
    Hours Hours // 7
}

type CalendarSlow map[Username]map[Year]map[Date]Hours
```

If i want, for example, from my API to return all hours for given date range I can write these two benchmarks to test which data structure is better:

```golang
func BenchmarkNew(b *testing.B) {
    c := make(CalendarFast)
    c.Update(context.TODO())

    from, _ := time.Parse("2006-01-02", "2023-01-01")
    to, _ := time.Parse("2006-01-02", "2023-02-01")

    isInRange := func(t, from, to time.Time) bool {
        return (t.After(from) && t.Before(to)) || t.Equal(from) || t.Equal(to)
    }

    b.ResetTimer()

    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        // result is map[username]map[date]hours
        result := make(map[string]map[string]float64)
        for username, years := range c {
            if _, ok := result[username]; !ok {
                result[username] = make(map[string]float64)
            }

            for _, dates := range years {
                for i, n := 0, len(dates); i < n; i++ {
                    if isInRange(dates[i].Time, from, to) {
                        result[username][dates[i].Time.String()] = dates[i].Hours
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkOld(b *testing.B) {
    c := make(CalendarSlow)
    c.Update(context.TODO())

    from, _ := time.Parse("2006-01-02", "2023-01-01")
    to, _ := time.Parse("2006-01-02", "2023-02-01")

    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        result := make(map[string]map[string]float64)
        for username, years := range c {
            if _, ok := result[username]; !ok {
                result[username] = make(map[string]float64)
            }

            for _, items := range years {
                for date, hours := range items {
                    t, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02", date)
                    if err != nil {
                        continue
                    }

                    if (t.After(from) && t.Before(to)) || t.Equal(from) || t.Equal(to) {
                        result[username][date] = hours
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I has following benchmarks, which shows that searching range in array is much faster, that search each element in map:

```
BenchmarkNew-4  285    4208045 ns/op  692965 B/op  6303 allocs/op
BenchmarkOld-4   39   29672935 ns/op  621877 B/op  1407 allocs/op
```

My Question is: how can I push performance even further? Should i change data structure to another?

I need speed because i receive a lot of calls to my current PHP API and find out that micro service in Go can easily handle 1k rps with only 10m cpu and 64Mib of memory in k8s

I already satisfied with array for "time.Time" approach, but curious of another implementations.

UPD:

| test | iterations | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mine with array | 229 | 5259548 ns/op |
| erik258 | 414 | 2892932 ns/op |

Comment: "Maximum performance" doesn't exist. It costs an infinite amount of money, because no matter how well you make something perform, you can spend enough time and money to find a way to make it faster. Instead, profile for "good enough", and if you aren't good getting good enough performance for your context, optimize.

Comment: Yes, iterating over slices is faster than iterating over maps, so if all you ever need to do is iterate of the entire structure in order then use slices. What is best depends on actual data and how it's used, which we know nothing about, so we can't tell you what may or may not be better for your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description the data is static and you're only reading the source files once at program startup.

Why not order each employee's date array so once you get beyond the end date you can stop checking the rest of the dates?

Why does `year` map exist?.  Just one more thing to iterate over.

And why store all dates as strings, then have to parse them each time you want to filter by date range?  Why not use `time.Time`?  Much more efficient in memory and removes the need to parse over and over again.

I would use a `map[Username][]struct{date time.Time, hours int}`, order the array  after I read it once, then iterate more like this:

```
for username, dates := range c {
   for shift := range dates {
      if shift.date.Before(from) {
         continue
      } else if shift.date.After(to) {
         break
      }
      if _, ok := result[username]; !ok {
         result[username] = make(map[string]float64)
      }
      result[username][shift.date] = shift.hours
   }
}
```

Comment: Wow! Your method with "continue" and "break" is exactly 2 times faster! Thank you for an example.

Comment: map[Username]map[Year] I use to quickly find the calendar for the whole year.

Comment: it's essentially an index.  I'd be curious if sqlite was comparably performant - storing this stuff in load-at-start json files seems inconvenient, but might be good for your use case